# Why does this PHP method declaration not recognize the namespace of the type hint?

Tags: php, interface, namespaces, php-5.3

I'm trying to write a library based on [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions), which provides this interface:

```php
namespace Gedmo\Mapping;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

interface Driver {
  public function readExtendedMetadata(ClassMetadata $meta, array &$config);

  public function setOriginalDriver($driver);
}
```

In my own code I implement this interface:

```php
namespace Avit\Schedulable\Mapping\Driver;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Driver,
    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

class Annotation implements Driver {
  public function readExtendedMetadata(ClassMetadata $meta, array &$config) {
    // my implementation
  }
}
```

The error I get says: **Declaration of Avit\Schedulable\Mapping\Driver\Annotation::readExtendedMetadata() must be compatible with that of Gedmo\Mapping\Driver::readExtendedMetadata()**

I can avoid the error if I remove the `ClassMetadata` type hint on my method.

I've googled some information that says this error happens when the namespace is mismatched. This makes sense since I'm declaring this class in my own namespace, however, I'm aliasing the same Doctrine namespace for `ClassMetadata` that the original `Driver` interface uses.

Why is the type hint not recognized?

Comment: Is the missing semicolon after the use in the second code a typo?

Comment: Do you have an own `ClassMetadata`-class or -interface in your namespace?

Comment: Fixed the typo. @KingCrunch, no, I don't have my own definition of that class anywhere. Even if I did, wouldn't the one named in the "use" clause take precedence?

Comment: @AndrewVit No, it wouldn't, but you should get a warning, or notice then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in `Driver` here
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/Driver.php
seems do not having `ClassMetadata` type hint.

Mind if check the one you are using?

Comment: Thanks, looks like this was a [recent change](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/commit/afbf04fd8aeb1567d98da39dacb64961270e992f) in this library. Still, I'm confused why it wouldn't see it as the same method signature.